# Oracle SQL dev, count under heading

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently trying to get the database to list a interest job number, and users title and count the users interested in the interest description. The query is meant to count under the heading "No. Users Interested. Interests with no interested users should be excluded.

```
(PK) = Primary Key
(FK) = Foreign Key
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
Building(buildingNum(PK), Description, instname, buildName, state, postcode)
User(UNum(PK), buildingNum(FK), Surname, FirstName, initials, title)
File(FileNum(PK), title)
UserAccount(FileNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK))
Job(JobNum(PK), id, title)
Interest(JobNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK), Description)
```

So far i have tried the following block of code:

```
select I.JobNum, U.title, count(I.description) AS 'No. Academics Interested'
from Interest I join Users U
where U.UNum = I.UNum AND I.description != null;
```

I'm struggling with how to do this using a sub query, all i receive is an error as this doesn't work. I'm not sure of how I do the Count(I.description) under a heading and how i should be doing it. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

You presumably would need to aggregation using `GROUP BY` here:

```
SELECT
    i.JobNum,
    u.title,
    COUNT(i.description) AS "No. Academics Interested"
FROM Interest i
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON u.UNum = i.UNum
GROUP BY
    i.JobNum,
    u.title;
```

Note that the check `I.description != null` (which should actually be `i.description IS NOT NULL`) is not necessary here, because the `COUNT` function by default does not count `NULL` values.